# Get a sum from a temp table into my select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL that calls a stored procedure and return a number of rows from various users.  Each row has an amount and I want to get the sum of those amounts per user into another select query.

So the query to get the amounts;

```
Declare @tempUserPurchases table(
    Email nvarchar(50), Amount money
)

-- get all the data into the temp table.
insert into @tempUserPurchases
    exec stpGetUserPurchases @CompanyId = 312546
```

So the above generates several records per member each with an email and an amount and all for the specified company.

Now I have another Select statement and I want to put the sum for each member from the query above into the corresponding members record.

```
select 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Email,
    tblSum.Amount
Into #returnedTable
from
    tblMembers
    Cross Join
    (
        Select sum(Amount) Amount from @tempUserPurchases
        Where email = returnedTable.email
    ) tblSum
```

So at the end I should end up with a single row per email with the summed amount from the tempUserPurchases table.

I can't figure out how to get the email into the Cross Join.  Or am I not even close on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a `CROSS JOIN` because that will give you a Cartesian product. You can use a `LEFT JOIN` (or if you're sure there will always be a match in your table variable you can use an `INNER JOIN` as it will be slightly faster).

Like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, tblSum.Amount
FROM tblMembers
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT email, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM @tempUserPurchases
    GROUP BY email
) AS tblSum ON tblSum.email=tblMembers.email
```

The way you're trying to do it is called a correlated subquery. In order for that to work it would need to be in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, (
        SELECT SUM(Amount)
        FROM @tempUserPurchases AS t
        WHERE t.email=m.email
    ) AS Amount
FROM tblMembers AS m
```

However, the join method will perform much better because the correlated subquery will have to be evaluated for every row. Using the `JOIN` method the aggregation query will only be run once.